# Opening and Closing of Browser using TOSCA

Tags: browser, automation, tosca

Recently i Started learning tosca. I have added extension for chrome. when i started to executing the opening and closing of an application. It opened the application in Microsoft edge and throwing an error that there is no such window title to close. if the same window is opened in chrome it is closing that window. what i want to say is opening the url using Mircosoft edge and closing is not happening in MS Edge. it is closing the window which is opened in google Chrome. How to get ride of this.

Answer (score 0):

Tosca is using your default Browser if there is no Browser defined in the TCP section.
If you want to use Chrome you have to define the TCP Browser with the value Chrome.
If you want to use edge you will need to install the Tosca Edge Extension.